Flink local run failing when trying to use StreamTableEnvironment
I am trying to run a flink job locally reading from a local iceberg table
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(configuration);
env.getConfig().enableObjectReuse();

final EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance()
                .inBatchMode()
                .build();

final StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, settings);

However, I am seeing the following error
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.MetadataDef.<init>(MetadataDef.java:48)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.MetadataDef.of(MetadataDef.java:64)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.BuiltInMetadata$PercentageOriginalRows.<clinit>(BuiltInMetadata.java:345)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.RelMdPercentageOriginalRows$RelMdPercentageOriginalRowsHandler.getDef(RelMdPercentageOriginalRows.java:231)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.ReflectiveRelMetadataProvider.reflectiveSource(ReflectiveRelMetadataProvider.java:134)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.RelMdPercentageOriginalRows.<clinit>(RelMdPercentageOriginalRows.java:42)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.DefaultRelMetadataProvider.<init>(DefaultRelMetadataProvider.java:42)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.DefaultRelMetadataProvider.<clinit>(DefaultRelMetadataProvider.java:28)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.RelOptCluster.<init>(RelOptCluster.java:97)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.RelOptCluster.create(RelOptCluster.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.FlinkRelOptClusterFactory$.create(FlinkRelOptClusterFactory.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.FlinkRelOptClusterFactory.create(FlinkRelOptClusterFactory.scala)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerContext.<init>(PlannerContext.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.<init>(PlannerBase.scala:121)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.BatchPlanner.<init>(BatchPlanner.scala:61)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultPlannerFactory.create(DefaultPlannerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.PlannerFactoryUtil.createPlanner(PlannerFactoryUtil.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.internal.StreamTableEnvironmentImpl.create(StreamTableEnvironmentImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.StreamTableEnvironment.create(StreamTableEnvironment.java:122)

I am using flink version 1.17.1. Any pointers will be helpful.

Apparently it was because of jacoco plugin. Jacoco instruments the code adding jacocoInit function. There is an assertion inside MetadataDef for the method count. Because of the added jacocoInit, it was failing
